# Understanding supervisor strategy in Akka

Tags: java, akka

I'm reading Akka documentation and now I'm at the section about [***UntypedActors***](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/java/untyped-actors.html#UntypedActor_API). I decided to try some examples:

Here are my actors:

Parent

```
private static class MyUntypedActor extends UntypedActor{

    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Recieved: " + message);
    }

    @Override
    public void preStart(){
        getContext().actorOf(AnotherUntypedActor.props()).tell("Process it", getSelf());
    }

    public static Props props(){
        return Props.create(MyUntypedActor.class);
    }
}
```

Child

```
private static class AnotherUntypedActor extends UntypedActor{

    public static Props props(){
        return Props.create(AnotherUntypedActor.class);
    }

    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("My: " + message);
        throw new RuntimeException("Crashed: " + getSelf());
    }
}
```

main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TimeoutException {
    ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create();
    Inbox inbox = Inbox.create(system);
    ActorRef actorRef = system.actorOf(MyUntypedActor.props());
    inbox.send(actorRef, "Message");
}
```

so, my child actors experienced failure and I thought the it should have notified the parent somehow.

But what I recieved was this:

```
Recieved: Message
My: Process it 
[ERROR] [07/14/2016 19:05:13.726] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://default/user/$a/$a] Crashed: Actor[akka://default/user/$a/$a#-950392568]
```

What does the supervision do actually? Child actor had faulted and what? I got just an error message in a log. What does supervisorStrategy mean? It's by default set to

```
OneForOneStrategy(-1,Duration.Inf,true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using supervisor strategy, you decide what should be done with supervised actor if it fails. You have to override `supervisionStrategy()` method within your parent actor and define strategy. I.e. (not sure if it's correct since I use Scala for Akka)

```
@Override
    public SupervisorStrategy supervisorStrategy() {
        return strategy;
    }

    private static SupervisorStrategy strategy =
            new OneForOneStrategy(10, Duration.create("1 minute"),
                    t -> {
                        if (t instanceof SomeException) {
                            return restart();
                        } else {
                            return stop();
                        }
                    });
```

In this case, if `SomeException` occurs, actor will be restarted. Otherwise, it will be stopped. You can choose one of four strategies. 
[Read documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/java/fault-tolerance.html)

Tip: Create specific exceptions!

Comment: So, the principal purpose of the strategy is to define a way of how to react if exception's thrown. And the actual decision's made within the decider function. By default it does nothing (as far as I can tell), right?

Comment: Pretty much. And as far as I remember, default is `Restart`.